# Tabulate Area for large datasets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-9.3, area, tabulate

I have been struggling trying to use Tabulate Area in Arc 9.3 for a large raster dataset.

I have one raster with 8 land uses and another vector layer with zones (which I converted to a raster with the same resolution as the raster with 8 land uses, I also used the snap raster function when I did this).

When I use tabulate area separately for the two datasets, I get different areas. 
To cross check, I tabulated area using one of the polygons in the vector dataset for tabulate area, and got quite a significant difference in area as well.

Any suggestions on what would be the best way to tabulate area for a large dataset?

Answer (score 3):

You need to be very careful using tabulate area.  The tool is helpful, but has some "gotchas".

- Watch out for sending in overlapping zones.  **Zones cannot be overlapping** as the vector is rasterized and two zones cannot be represented in the same cell.  Its a bummer Esri doesn't handle this out-of-the-box.
- Setting **snap raster** is great, but you should also set the **output extent** environment variable.
- If all else fails, **manually convert your zones to a raster** and run Tabulate Area using the raster as your zones.  This will may give you more consistent results. The documentation states:

> It is recommended that you only use rasters as the zone and class
>   inputs, as it offers you greater control over the vector-to-raster
>   conversion. This will help ensure that you consistently get the
>   expected results.

In general, you really need to closely read the tool's documentation.  I've gotten burned pretty bad on Tabulate Area and Zonal Statistics so beware...

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=tabulate_area